# hide div when it contain not equal attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have 2 type of div class `a` and `b` , attr is `data-type`. When I click `a` with `data-type` is `test1` , In `b` all `data-type` not equal to `test1` will be hide , only left div attr is `test1`. Any idea how to to this ?

```js
 $(".a").click(function () {
        var a_datatype = $(this).attr("data-type");
        var b_datatype = $(".b").attr("data-type");
   if(a_datatype ! = b_datatype){
         $(".b").hide();
     }
 });
```

```css
.a{
  float:left;
  cursor:pointer;
  }
.a:hover{
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  }
.b{
  float:right;
   
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a" data-type="test1">Name1</div>
<div class="a" data-type="test2">Name2</div>
<div class="a" data-type="test3">Name3</div>


<div class="b" data-type="test1">NewName1</div>
<div class="b" data-type="test1">NewName2</div>
<div class="b" data-type="test2">NewName3</div>
<div class="b" data-type="test2">NewName4</div>
<div class="b" data-type="test3">NewName5</div>
<div class="b" data-type="test3">NewName6</div>
```

Comment: It should be if(a_datatype != b_datatype) . Don't leave space between ! and =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var a_datatype = $(this).data("type");

$(".b:not([data-type='" + a_datatype  + "'])").hide();
$(".b[data-type='" + a_datatype  + "']").show();
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jf0obaho/)

Comment: oh ~ really have to thanks u so so much ~ i think of this code using my 3 hours , thanks u !

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for that, using the callback variation:

```
$('.a').on('click', function(e) {
    var type = $(this).data('type');
    $('.a, .b').filter(function() {
         return $(this).data('type') != type;
    })
    .hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, `b_datatype` will always be equal to 'test1', because there are multiple `$('.b')` so it selects the first one. You need to filter each one of them:

```
$(".a").click(function () {
    var a_datatype = $(this).attr("data-type");

    // here, use .show to reset all of them to visible
    $(".b").show().filter(function(){
        return a_datatype != $(this).attr("data-type");
    }).hide();

});
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Answer (score 1):

Despite I'm liking more the solutions provided by @blex and @giorgio, here is a snippet to do that without the filter, just to provide some variety:

```
$(".a").click(function () {
        var this_datatype = $(this).attr("data-type");
    $('.b').each(function(i, v) {
        $(this).attr('data-type') != this_datatype ? $(this).hide() : $(this).show();
    });
 });
```

slightly different approach, but still works:

http://jsfiddle.net/r08dm2um/2/